# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'urllib.request' has no attribute ' urlopen' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, syntax-error

I was learning about accessing data through url in python ....And I have written following code

```
import json   
import urllib.request as ur  
url= input('Enter site: ')  
print( 'Retrieving ', url)  
data = ur.urlopen(url).read()  
info = json.loads(data)  
tot = 0  
print ('Retrieved ', len(data), 'characters')  
print ('Count: ', len(info['comments']))  
for i in range(0, len(info['comments'])):  
   tot += int(info['comments'][i]['count'])  
print ('Sum ', tot)
```

And I was getting the following error

```
    data = ur.urlopen(url).read()
    AttributeError: partially initialized module 'urllib.request' has no attribute '
    urlopen' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Can anyone help me?? Thank you in advance !!

Comment: Did you give your script the name of [one of the modules imported by urllib.request](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/urllib/request.py#L84) - or some module of the standard library?

Comment: Sorry I am unable to understand you

Comment: What is the name of the file that contains your code?

Comment: file name is  : test.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue earlier & here is the fix.

I used the name `urlilib` as my file name:

[image]

I changed my file name to some other words & it WORKED FOR ME! :)

[image]

Hope you find the answer to be simple & useful

Answer (score 2):

The only cause of this error is if you have a file that is named the same as the module which leads to a circular import. It also doesn't have to be the same script, it can also be any other files in the same folder.

Check and rename your files to ensure that they don't contain the module names such as `requests.py`, `urllib.py`, or any other relevancies. Fix this and it should solve your problem.

Comment: I changed name of file...But still facing same error

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall python

Comment: Is this file based in a  folder? You may try to reinstall the module again and see if that helps

Comment: I worked on Python IDLE ...But still gives error when I use Command Prompt. What is the reason for this??

Comment: I can't think of any other issues that can cause this problem. I am sure there are some file conflicts- you can try typing `dir` or even `tree` in your cmd prompt and somewhere there, there should be some conflicting names.